# What does "./" do in href?

Tags: html

I know that for example:

```
../path/to/file.html
```

does first jump from the current directory to the next higher directory and then enters
   path/to/file.html

However what does

```
   ./path/to/file.html
```

do? I couldn't find an answer on the net so far :(

Comment: https://www.golinuxhub.com/2013/12/what-is-and-in-unixlinux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is a reference to the current directory. See: [Path (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Unix_style)

Comment: lets assume that <base href="/"> was set on the landing page. Does this change the behavior/outcome of "."? Will the "current" directory be the rootdirectory?

Comment: Nothing changes the meaning of `.`. So yes, if you set your base to `/`, all your relative routes will be relative to `/`.

Comment: @Frolo321 keep in mind that in `base`, the root `/` means domain root, not system root.

Answer (score 2):

`./` or `.` is ALWAYS the current directory.

`~/`(on Linux) is the current user's home directory. 
For you to know as well: `cd %userprofile%` (on Windows) sends you to home user directory

Imagine I you're in repository2 and you want to include the file.txt:

```
~/ ---> Pictures
   ---> Documents  --> repository1 --> repository2 
   ---> Downloads
   ---> file.txt
```

You simply do:

```
../../file.txt
```

or

```
~/file.txt
```

And Imagine you want to move the file.txt to the current repository:

```
mv ../../file.txt .
```

Comment: `~/` is NOT the root directory. `~/` is the current user's home directory. The root directory is `/`.

Comment: Keep in mind the tilde (~) does not work on windows machines. See https://superuser.com/a/332872 for a windows "equivalent".